# Hide the notification for a foreground service (Root method included)

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

How to hide the notification for a foreground service (ie nowhere in the notification bar)?

This behavior is illustrated in apps like Switchr and Open Mic+

Answer (score 0):

For non-root users who are 4.3+, you'll have to instruct your users to go to App Settings and disable "Show Notifications"

For root users use the following code:

```
public static boolean requestRoot()
{
    Process p; 
    try { 
       // Preform su to get root privledges
       p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"); 

       // Attempt to write a file to a root-only 
       DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream()); 
       os.writeBytes("echo \"Do I have root?\" >/system/sd/temporary.txt\n");

       // Close the terminal
       os.writeBytes("exit\n"); 
       os.flush(); 
       try { 
          p.waitFor(); 
               if (p.exitValue() != 255) { 
                   return true;
               } 
               else { 
                   return false;
               } 
       } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
          return false;
       } 
    } catch (IOException e) { 
       return false;
    }

}
public static void hideNotification(Context context)
{
    Process p; 
    try { 
       // Preform su to get root privledges
       p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"); 
       DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream()); 
       os.writeBytes("service call notification 6 s16 " + context.getPackageName() + " i32 " + context.getApplicationInfo().uid + " i32 0");

       // Close the terminal
       os.writeBytes("exit\n"); 
       os.flush(); 
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {}
}
public static void showNotification(Context context)
{
    Process p; 
    try { 
       // Preform su to get root privledges
       p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"); 
       DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream()); 
       os.writeBytes("service call notification 6 s16 " + context.getPackageName() + " i32 " + context.getApplicationInfo().uid + " i32 1");

       // Close the terminal
       os.writeBytes("exit\n"); 
       os.flush(); 
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {}
}
```